# Maximize violating constraints

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization

I have

```
Maximize[{(h*10)/(300*(100 - (l^.5 + d^.4 + H^.6))), (l + d + H + h) == 669,      
  l > 0, d > 0, H > 0, h > 0}, {h, l, d, H}]
```

I believe this should maximize my formula, but when I run it, I get

> The function value 12073.4 -0.284149 I is not a real number at {d,h,H,l} = {-28.781,  682.337, 2.43779, 13.006}

Can anyone help me figure out how to enter this problem so I get the correct answer? I thought I'd explicitly made it not evaluate the formula for any variable less than 0, but it seems to be trying to do that.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica SE, be sure to read the [guidelines](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/asking) of the site

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suspect you are correct in your assessment. Since there are approximate numbers in the input, `Maximize` punts to `NMaximize`, which uses penalty methods to enforce some constraints (not sure why it needs them here for linear constraints; I need to check into that).

You can get better behavior by forcing real values.

```
NMaximize[{Re[(h*10)/(300*(100 - (l^.5 + d^.4 + H^.6)))], (l +
      d + H + h) == 669, l > 0, d > 0, H > 0, h > 0}, {h, l, d, H}]

(* Out[2]= {0.2386596519573097, {h -> 612.1588854816083, 
  l -> 12.8156550218952, d -> 5.775648336504858, 
  H -> 38.24981115999163}} *)
```

Answer (score 11):

Using a symbolic functionality like `Maximize` with an expression involving approximate numbers is not in general a good idea, even though `Maximize` calls automatically `NMaximize` in such cases. However if we rewrite the expression to an exact form, then `Maximize` will run very long time returning no symbolic results.

The problem one encounters here is most likely not a very smart approach for the constraint equation specified here as `(l + d + H + h) == 669`. When the system puts the constraint to the expression involving fractional powers it fails, nonetheless we can simply solve this constraint getting rid off one variable e.g. `h`.  so we can get the result immediatley this way:

```
NMaximize[{(10 (669 - l - d - H))/(300 (100 - (l^(1/2) + d^(4/10) + H^(6/10)))),
            l > 0, d > 0, H > 0}, {l, d, H}]
```

> ```
> {0.23866, {l -> 12.8156, d -> 5.77564, H -> 38.2498}}
> ```

now we solve the constraint:

```
NSolve[(l + d + H + h) == 669 /. Last @ %, h]
```

> ```
>  {{h -> 612.159}}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

try FindMaximum.

```
FindMaximum[{(h*10)/(300*(100 - (l^.5 + d^.4 + H^.6))), (l + d + H + 
     h) == 669, l > 0, d > 0, H > 0, h > 0}, {h, l, d, H}]

(*{0.23866, {h -> 612.159, l -> 12.8158, d -> 5.77578, H -> 38.2499}}*)
```

Comment: `FindMaximum` returns a local maximum, here it appears to be the same as the global one, however in general it couldn't be a sufficient approach.