# Maximize simple polynomial: Wrong answer (Gives the minimum!)

Tags: mathematical-optimization, polynomials, constraint

I want to maximize `poly` under the constraints $g1,g2,g3=0$

```
poly = x1^4 + 2 x1^2 x2^2 + 2 x1^2 x3^2 + 2 x1^2 x4^2 + 0.2 x2^4 + 
       0.4 x2^2 x3^2 + 0.4 x2^2 x4^2 + 0.2 x3^4 + 0.4 x3^2 x4^2 + 0.2 x4^4;

g1 = 6.4 x1 x2^3 + 6.4 x1 x2 x3^2 + 6.4 x1 x2 x4^2;
g2 = 6.4 x1 x2^2 x3 + 6.4 x1 x3^3 + 6.4 x1 x3 x4^2;
g3 = -1 + x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2 + x4^2;
```

Therefore I used all these different methods, but none of them work.

```
Maximize[{poly, g1 == 0, g2 == 0, g3 == 0}, {x1, x2, x3, x4}]
```

> {0.2, {x1 -> -1.11978*10^-9, x2 -> -0.20688, x3 -> 0.930234, 
>     x4 -> -0.303094}}

```
NMaximize[{poly, g1 == 0, g2 == 0, g3 == 0}, {x1, x2, x3, x4}]
```

> {0.2, {x1 -> -1.11978*10^-9, x2 -> -0.20688, x3 -> 0.930234, 
>     x4 -> -0.303094}}

```
FindMaximum[{poly, g1 == 0, g2 == 0, g3 == 0}, {x1, x2, x3, x4}]
```

> {0.2, {x1 -> -4.20087*10^-11, x2 -> -0.705858, 
>     x3 -> -0.705858, x4 -> -0.059409}}

```
FindMaxValue[{poly, g1 == 0, g2 == 0, g3 == 0}, {x1, x2, x3, x4}]
```

> 0.2

But there is the obvious solution $\vec{x}=({1,0,0,0})$

```
poly /. x1 -> 1 /. x2 -> 0 /. x3 -> 0 /. x4 -> 0
```

> 1.

which also fulfills the constraints:

```
g1 /. x1 -> 1 /. x2 -> 0 /. x3 -> 0 /. x4 -> 0
g2 /. x1 -> 1 /. x2 -> 0 /. x3 -> 0 /. x4 -> 0
g3 /. x1 -> 1 /. x2 -> 0 /. x3 -> 0 /. x4 -> 0
```

> 0.
>
> 0.
>
> 0.

Actually the value 0.2 is the global **minimum** of the polynomial under the constraints...

Comment: You use (inexact) machine precision numbers, which makes `Maximize` switch over to numeric mode. Try `Rationalize` on your input (which delivers `{1, {x1 -> -1, x2 -> 0, x3 -> 0, x4 -> 0}}`).

Comment: Straight from the help: "If Maximize is given an expression containing approximate numbers, it automatically calls NMaximize."

Comment: For `NMaximize`, using `Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"` or `"RandomSearch"` will give correct answers. Or using higher `WorkingPrecision` will give correct answers under any `Method`.

Comment: @Silvia hehe we had parallel evolution - just wanted to augment on `Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"` ;-). `NMaximize` being stuck at the minimum is a surpring coincidence though.

Comment: @Silvia ops! I've read your comment just after answering (the same!).If you plan to post an answer I'll remove mine

Comment: @YvesKlett Still I feel surprised the default setting gives a global minimum. (Or does it?)

Comment: @belisarius I think your answer is exactly what I can say about the question! :)

Comment: I would do it this way: `Maximize[Rationalize[{poly, g1 == 0, g2 == 0, g3 == 0}], {x1, x2, x3, x4}]`.  `NMaximize` sometimes yields wrong answers when working with constraints, see e.g. [Maximize violating constraints](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59706/maximize-violating-constraints/59708#59708)

Comment: `FindMaximum` in recent versions appears to give a correct result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NMaximize[{poly, g1 == 0, g2 == 0, g3 == 0}, {x1, x2, x3, x4}, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]

(* {1., {x1 -> 0.999999, x2 -> 0.0000693388, x3 -> -0.00106407, x4 -> 0.00102883}}*)
```

or

```
NMaximize[{poly, g1 == 0, g2 == 0, g3 == 0}, {x1, x2, x3, x4}, WorkingPrecision -> 15]
(* {1.00000006317100, {x1 -> -0.999999798232786, 
                       x2 -> 0.0000936576222886767, x3 -> -0.000460488000721031, 
                       x4 -> 0.000462924413626347}} *)
```

Curiously:

```
sol = FindInstance[ poly == 1 && And @@ {g1 == 0, g2 == 0, g3 == 0}, {x1, x2, x3, x4}, Reals, 10]

(* {{x1 -> -1., x2 -> 0, x3 -> 0, x4 -> 0}, {x1 -> 1., x2 -> 0, x3 -> 0,  x4 -> 0}}*)

{poly /. sol, {g1, g2, g3} /. sol}

(* {{1., 1.}, {{0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0.}}} *)
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's something I noticed.

The maximization works if you use exact rational numbers instead of real numbers as the coefficients:

```
poly = x1^4 + 2 x1^2 x2^2 + 2 x1^2 x3^2 + 2 x1^2 x4^2 + 2 /10 x2^4 + 
   4/10 x2^2 x3^2 + 4/10 x2^2 x4^2 + 2/10 x3^4 + 4/10 x3^2 x4^2 + 
   2/10 x4^4;
g1 = 64/10 x1 x2^3 + 64/10 x1 x2 x3^2 + 64/10 x1 x2 x4^2;
g2 = 64/10 x1 x2^2 x3 + 64/10 x1 x3^3 + 64/10 x1 x3 x4^2;
g3 = -1 + x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2 + x4^2;
```

And the result you get:

```
In[104]:= Maximize[{poly, {g1 == 0, g2 == 0, g3 == 0}}, {x1, x2, x3, x4}]
Out[104]= {1, {x1 -> -1, x2 -> 0, x3 -> 0, x4 -> 0}}
```

I'm afraid I can't explain the wrong answer if you have real-valued coefficients, though...